# How to import CSV data in a single column dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I know where this error is coming from.

I try to `df = pd.read_csv("\words.csv")`

In this CSV, I have a column with each row filled with text.
Sometimes in this text, I have this separator a comma `,`.
[image]

But I have practically all the possible symbols so I can't give it a good separator! (I have `;` too)

The only thing that I know is that I only need 1 column. Is there a way to force the number of columns and not interpret the others "separators"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are aiming to have one column, one way to achieve this goal is to use a newline `\n` as a separator like so:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("\words.csv", sep="\n")
```

Since there will always be one line per row it is bound to always detect one column.